# MVC multiple buttons with multiple sessions (ex: upvotes)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm trying to make a page where you can upvote dynamically added posts in MVC 5 and count the upvotes of each and every single post.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="@item.ImgURL" style="max-width: 200px;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Upvotes)
                    <button id="upvotes">Upvote</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    <button class="js-delete" data-model-id="@item.Id">Delete</button> |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Add to Hot Page", "AddToHot", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

The upvotes are displayed in front of the button and is there some way to assign that button to the number of upvotes using Sessions?

And p.s. there are multiple posts with their own specific number of upvotes.

Addition to the code:

```
public ActionResult Upvote(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Meme meme = db.Memes.Find(id);
            if (meme == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            meme.Upvotes++;
            db.Memes.Remove(db.Memes.Find(id));
            db.Memes.Add(meme);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(meme);
        }
```

P.S, I've changed `<button id="upvotes">Upvote</button>` to

`@Html.ActionLink("Upvote", "Upvote", new { id = item.Id })`

Answer (score 0):

`<button id="upvotes">Upvote</button>` in a for loop will render all buttons with same value in the Id property. Change it to something like this:

```
<button id="upvotes@item.Id">Upvote</button>
```

That will result in the followings:

```
<button id="upvotes1">Upvote</button>
<button id="upvotes2">Upvote</button>
<button id="upvotes3">Upvote</button>
...
```

Coming back to the actual problem, you did not share the code of the action that handles the upvote. And what is the return type of that action?

I am assuming it is an ajax action and a child action, Then I am guessing you are returning the total count of vote for the post from that action.

In that case you can append the returned number (for example 15) to the container that displays the total number.

Comment: If that solves your problem that is great. Otherwise please share the action that renders the page and also the action that is executed when you click the upvote button.